# How to make Pandas unpack JSON data into proper DataFrame instead of list of dicts

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to parse the data at http://dev.hsl.fi/tmp/citybikes/stations_20170503T071501Z into a Pandas DataFrame. Using `read_json` gives me a list of dicts instead of a proper DataFrame with the variable names as columns:

```
In [1]:

data = pd.read_json("http://dev.hsl.fi/tmp/citybikes/stations_20170503T071501Z")
print(data)

Out[1]:

                                                result
0    {'name': '001 Kaivopuisto', 'coordinates': '60...
1    {'name': '002 Laivasillankatu', 'coordinates':...
..                                                 ...
149  {'name': '160 Nokkala', 'coordinates': '60.147...
150  {'name': '997 Workshop Helsinki', 'coordinates...

[151 rows x 1 columns]
```

This happens with all `orient` option. I've tried `json_normalize()` to no avail as well and a few other things I found here. How could I make this into a sensible DataFrame? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Option 1**
Use `pd.DataFrame` on the list of dictionaries

```
pd.DataFrame(data['result'].values.tolist())

   avl_bikes          coordinates  free_slots                    name  operative style  total_slots
0         12  60.155411,24.950391          18         001 Kaivopuisto       True    CB           30
1          3  60.159715,24.955212           9     002 Laivasillankatu       True                 12
2          0  60.158172,24.944808          16  003 Kapteeninpuistikko       True                 16
3          0  60.160944,24.941859          14           004 Viiskulma       True                 14
4         16  60.157935,24.936083          16           005 Sepänkatu       True                 32
```

---

**Option 2**
Use `apply`

```
data.result.apply(pd.Series)

   avl_bikes          coordinates  free_slots                    name  operative style  total_slots
0         12  60.155411,24.950391          18         001 Kaivopuisto       True    CB           30
1          3  60.159715,24.955212           9     002 Laivasillankatu       True                 12
2          0  60.158172,24.944808          16  003 Kapteeninpuistikko       True                 16
3          0  60.160944,24.941859          14           004 Viiskulma       True                 14
4         16  60.157935,24.936083          16           005 Sepänkatu       True                 32
```

---

**Option 3**
Or you could fetch the `json` yourself and strip out the `results`

```
import urllib, json
url = "http://dev.hsl.fi/tmp/citybikes/stations_20170503T071501Z"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())

df = pd.DataFrame(data['result'])
df

   avl_bikes          coordinates  free_slots                    name  operative style  total_slots
0         12  60.155411,24.950391          18         001 Kaivopuisto       True    CB           30
1          3  60.159715,24.955212           9     002 Laivasillankatu       True                 12
2          0  60.158172,24.944808          16  003 Kapteeninpuistikko       True                 16
3          0  60.160944,24.941859          14           004 Viiskulma       True                 14
4         16  60.157935,24.936083          16           005 Sepänkatu       True                 32
```

Comment: Option 2 worked previously as `data.result.apply` but the current form `data.apply` does not. Otherwise, very good answer, thank you very much!

Comment: @basse that was my bad during editing.  Thanks for the fix

Answer (score 1):

The approaches in the accepted answer work great, so this is just a more recent (2022) FYI:

In later versions of Pandas (1.0>), you can also use `json_normalize` ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)).

```
json_obj = {
    
    'key': 123,
    'field1': 'blah',
    'info': {
        'contacts': {
          'email': {
              'foo': 'foo@abc.com',
              'bar': 'bar@abc.com'
          },
          'tel': '123456789',
      }
    }
}


pd.json_normalize(json_obj)
```